# Can There Be Multiple Subjects in a Clause Where One Is the Subject of Another Clause

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, syntax, infinitive, case

I want to construct "I like learning, but learning from a book only can be boring": "Discere amo, sed discere a libro ipso sit taediosum."

I was wondering if you can omit "discere" in the second clause: "Discere amo, sed a libro ipso sit taediosum," "ego" being the subject of the first clause and "discere" the second. And also whether "a" can be also: "Discere amo, sed libro ipso sit taediosum."

Comment: You can omit *discere* as a subject in the second clause, since it can likely be understood as the subject of *sit*. Is that what you are asking? Because I don't get that impression when I read your title question. I also do not see one clause clause with multiple subjects, but I see two clauses with one subject each: 1) implicit *ego* and 2) implicit or explicit *discere*.